# 2 column R parsing Query

Tags: r

I've been searching for a while and I can't seem to find anything that really suits my needs answer wise...

I have a data set like this:

```
  X    Y
  Data Data
  Data Data
  Data Data
  Data Data
```

Etc.

I'm tasked with running a T_test on said columns. Now I've gotten this to run by re-working my CSV File to this format

```
X Data
X Data
X Data
X Data
Y Data
Y Data
Y Data
Y Data
```

I'm NOT asking for the T-Test command or over all code, JUST how to read the columns in example one like I did in Example 2. From what reading I did, I surmised that you HAVE to run it like sample 2 where you have your group on the left and data on the right.

I've seen Similar posts but it doesn't seem to answer the question I'm asking and if it DOES it's going RIGHT over my head. I originally tried this in Python but ultimately gave up. If you can help please put it in Lame-mans-terms as I'm still VERY Extremely new to R.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are you asking how to reshape the data to the second format? Or how to interpret it? For R's t-test, I think you can run either `t.test(x, y)` in which case your first format is fine. Or `t.test(data~x)`, in which case the second format is fine

Comment: I'll give the t.test(x,y) A try and see what it does. But I just want to beable to run a T-test on said data perferably without having to re-format the Csv File. And by Data I'm talking like in this example lets say we're talking about cars and MPG Averages

Just gave it a shot, and it's saying x not found.

Comment: what code did you run exactly?

Comment: Data = read.csv(FileAddressHere)

t.test( X, Y, data=Data,
              var.equal=TRUE,
              conf.level=0.95)

It works with the other command t.test(Car ~ MPG , data=Data etc.)(X and Y Substituted for example) (Car ~ MPG Also substituted in for example)

Comment: LET ME RESTATE I just realized I may be confusing you. I have 2 CSV files, one with the first set up, the other thats been re-formatted in a way that works. The second sample Where the group is on the left and the data is on the right, The code for IT works. But I want to try to run it without modifying the CSV File at all. Sorry!

Comment: In the end it didn't matter what format was used, So I got it working as intended. Thanks to all who helped!